# How to find 'selected' ListTile with Flutter widget tester?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing widget tests for a simple `ListView` with `ListTile` elements in Flutter, and want to test if element has been highlighted.

How do I find a widget of the given type that matches 'selected' criteria?

```dart
Finder finder = find.byType(ListTile); // how to filter out only selected
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `byWidgetPredicate`:

```dart
Finder finder = find.byWidgetPredicate((w) => w is ListTile && w.selected);
```